# Typescript complains of type only when variable is imported

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, supabase, deno

I'm running a simple HTTP server, via Deno, on Supabase hosting.
When I move the routes definition in external files, TypeScript kicks in and starts to complain about argument types.

**Note:** I am *not* using TS in my code, I'm working in vanilla JS.

---

## What was working

This is the `server.ts`:

```
import { Application, Router } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v11.1.0/mod.ts";

const router = new Router()

const app = new Application();
app.use(router.routes());
await app.listen({ port: 4000 });
```

If I simply extract the `Router` instance inside another module, then Typescript starts to complain of invalid types.

---

## What broke it

I just create a `routes.js`:

```
import { Router } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";

const router = new Router();

export default router;
```

and use it in the `server.ts`:

```
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v11.1.0/mod.ts";
import router from "./routes.js";

const app = new Application();
app.use(router.routes()); // <--- THIS THROWS ERROR
await app.listen({ port: 4000 });
```

suddenly `use()` complains that the passed argument is not of the correct type:

> error: TS2345 [ERROR]: Argument of type 'import("https://deno.land/x/oak@v12.5.0/middleware.ts").Middleware<Record<string, any>, import("https://deno.land/x/oak@v12.5.0/context.ts").Context<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("https://deno.land/x/oak@v11.1.0/middleware.ts").Middleware<Record<string, any>, import("https://deno.land/x/oak@v11.1.0/context.ts").Context<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>>>'.
> Types of parameters 'context' and 'context' are incompatible.
> Type 'import("https://deno.land/x/oak@v11.1.0/context.ts").Context<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>>' is not assignable to type 'import("https://deno.land/x/oak@v12.5.0/context.ts").Context<Record<string, any>, Record<string, any>>'.
> Property '#wrapReviverReplacer' in type 'Context' refers to a different member that cannot be accessed from within type 'Context'.
> app.use(router.routes());

---

*Why `router.routes()` is suddenly of the wrong type, when I simply moved it out of the current file?*
It makes no sense to me.

How do I prevent this? I don't wanna have to start using types everywhere.
This code was working just fine without ending in Typescript land.

Comment: Importing exact versions of dependencies and using [lock files](https://deno.land/manual/basics/modules/integrity_checking) are recommended practices.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Reading better the massive & unreadable error message, i noticed that 2 different `oak` versions are mentioned: `v12.5.0` and `v11.1.0`.

The misalignment happened because VSCode suggests to "Quick Fix" the import with the version coming by following the redirect from the import URL. **I somehow got different versions while working on the code.**

The fix is to either:

- use the generic `https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts` (but it's exposed to breaking when fetching the `latest` version; and would need to `deno vendor lock`)
- or choose one of the explicit semversions mentioned, and use it consistently all around the code. (better solution, especially for code that goes to Production and shouldn't break)